# Mapping many-to-one with collection table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have a simple case with two entities `Machine` and `Product`, where a `Machine` can have zero or one `Product`. The reverse association (which would be a collection of some kind) is not needed in code.

The problem is in the database model which is legacy and I cannot alter the structure of the Machine table, so I created an extra table MachineProduct with foreign keys to both tables. Basically what you would do for a many-to-many relationship but in practice the MachineId in this table will be unique.

Now I need to map this in NHibernate. What I can do is map it as a many-to-many collection and make sure there's no more than one element in the Machine.Products collection but I feel there should be a more accurate way to deal with this. I guess that's what ORM mapping is all about.

I'm using NHibernate mapping-by-code but an XML mapping example will also do.

Comment: Does the existing Machine (table) have a FK to Product?  Like Machine.ParentProductSurrogateKey ?  ( I would think if it exists it would be nullable)....

Comment: No. If that would be the case I could use a simple many-to-one. The problem is I have no clearance to add that relationship in the database.

Comment: Ok, I understand better now.  You're trying to add a relationship that doesn't exist, but without modifying the original tables.  I don't have an answer, but let me look for something I ran across one time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my educated guess.

As you suggest, under normal M:N circumstances, MachineProduct would be a "link table" and repeats could be possible.

I think you can "singularize" the relationships...use the ".Unique()".

I think this is barking up the right tree.

```
public class MachineProductMap : ClassMap<MachineProductNHEntity>
{
    public MachineProductMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("MachineProduct");

        /* Your surrogate key setup here */
        Id(x => x.MachineProductUUID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Index("IX_MachineProduct_MachineProductUUID");

        References<MachineNHEntity>(x => x.ParentMachine)
            .Class(typeof(MachineNHEntity))
            .Not.Nullable()
             .Unique()
            .Column("ParentMachineUUID")
            .Index("IX_MachineProduct_ParentMachineUUID")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            ;
        ;


       References<ProductNHEntity>(x => x.ParentProduct)
            .Class(typeof(ProductNHEntity))
             .Nullable()
             .Unique()
            .Column("ParentProductUUID")
            .Index("IX_MachineProduct_ParentProductUUID")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            ;
        ;
    }
}
```

APPEND:

I think the above works, but you later state you don't want a middle-man entity.

So here is a another attempt using "Join".....

I think you want something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductSurrogateKey { get; set; } /* ID */
}   

public partial class Machine
    {
        public virtual Guid? MachineUUID { get; set; }
        public virtual Product TheProduct { get; set; }
    }

public class MachineMap : ClassMap<Machine>
{
    public MachineMap()
    {

        Table("Machine");

        Id(x => x.MachineUUID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Index("IX_Machine_MachineUUID");

        Join("MachineProductArtificialReferenceMaker", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("ParentMachineUUID");
            join.References(prop => prop.TheProduct);
        });

    }
}
```

This creates a table called "**MachineProductArtificialReferenceMaker**".

This table has a FK to Machine.MachineUUID. (not null)

And a FK to Product.ProductSurrogateKey (nullable)

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. Mapping the join table to an entity seems overkill since it doesn't add any other value.

Comment: I added a second answer.  It's "out there", but I think it works.

Comment: Thanks but this only works partially. It will create and update the MachineProduct record correctly but it will not delete that record when I set Machine.Product to null. The NHibernate Join concept is clearly not designed to cope with my use case.

Comment: That's all I got dude. Good luck.  Given the options, I'd just live with a benign row in the new table if it were me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i presume regular Many to Many should do the work, make sure dont reference the many to many relationship from Product.

```
<class name="Machine">
  <id ....>
  <bag name="Competencies" table="MachineProduct">
    <key column="machine_id"/>
   <many-to-many class="Product" column="product_id"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

Or regular One To Many works to.

```
<set name="MachineProduct" table="MachineProduct" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
  <key column="machine_id"/>
  <one-to-many class="MachineProduct"/>
</set>
```

Comment: The first solution is sort of what I have now but I feel there should be some better way since I don't actually need a collection. But as said in the question, I can add some code that manages the usage of the collection and expose it publicly as a regular association.

Comment: Im not sure what you need... what about one to one relationship?

Comment: Logically it is a many-to-one. Usually you can do this with just a foreign key in the database, but since we're not allowed to change the schema that contains the table Machine I'm using a join table (as with many-to-many relationships). What I'm looking for is an NHibernate mechanism that allows for a many-to-one mapping via a join table...